# C++で生成した配列要素のがソートできず、中身の要素数が不自然な問題について

Tags: c++

繰り返し処理の各処理におけるパフォーマンスをプログラムを書いています。
繰り返し処理は、行列の足し算で各要素を足す処理を指しています。
配列に入れた後、昇順にソートします。

[前回までの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57069/c%E3%81%A7%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%82%92%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC/57070#57070)に続いて、こちらの質問をします。

**解決したいこと**
①出力の配列がソートされていないですが、コンパイルエラーもなく、昇順にソートするにはコードをどのように修正すればいいのでしょうか。

②今回は足し算の各回数にかかる時間を計算しているので、2x2行列の場合

```
C[0][0]
C[0][1]
C[1][0]
C[1][1]
```

への足し算の結果を挿入で4回分の時間で、4要素が出力されると考えていましたが、24要素出力される理由がわかりません。

**出力**

```
$ ./simple
82, 85, 85, 155, 6.92884e-310, 6.92884e-310, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.24399e-314, 4.24399e-314, 4.24399e-314, 0, 0, 0, 2.122e-314, 0, 0,
```

**該当コード**

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

//繰り返し処理全体にかかった時間
using namespace std::chrono;


int main()
{
    #define N 2

    double A[N][N] = {
        {3.0, 5.0},
        {9.0, 5.0}
    };

    double B[N][N] = {
        {3.0, 6.0},
        {8.0, 9.0}
    };

    double C[N][N] = {
        {0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0}
    };
    int i, j, k, n;



    //各足し算にかかった時間を入れる配列
    std::vector<double> timedata;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
                //測定開始
                std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                C[i][j] += A[i][j]+B[i][j];
                //測定終了
                high_resolution_clock::time_point end = high_resolution_clock::now();
                double time =  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();

                //配列にappend
                timedata.push_back(time);
            }
    }

    std::vector<double> timedataResult;

    //配列をソート
    //timedataResult = 
    std::sort(timedata.begin(), timedata.end());
    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < sizeof(timedata); iIndex++) {
        std::cout << timedata[iIndex] << ", ";  // 結果をプリントしてみる。
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` は `vector` の要素数を意味しないので、こういう使い方はダメです。

昔の [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) とかだといろいろ書かなきゃいけなかったんですが、今どきの [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) なら range-based for というのを使うと楽で

```
for (auto value : timedata) std::cout << value << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```